# Running multiple instances of libpostal

Tags: python, python-3.x, geolocation

I have been testing libpostal for a few days now and I have the following use case:

I run 10 libpostal scripts simultaneously that analyse various documents, after a few seconds for most of them I get the following error:

```
ERR Averaged perceptron model could not be loaded at address_parser_load (address_parser.c:205) errno: Cannot allocate memory
```

I have a vague idea of how this could be solved, for example if I could tell all the script instances to share an already loaded model without creating each of them a separate one. As further information I am using pypostal.

I can see that it's because I run too many libpostal scripts at the same time, my question is, did anyone run into something similar and if so what was their solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for bumping such an old question, but I faced a similar problem recently when I tried using libpostal with Flask + GUnicorn. When using several workers, libpostal was not able to load the models.

The problem was solved by preloading the app with the `--preload` flag for GUnicorn:

```
gunicorn --workers=3 --preload main:APP
```